# How to escape CMD in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I've tried to start a server inside docker via the following syntax permutations:

1. `CMD [ "forever", "start", "server/server.js" ]`
2. `CMD [ "forever", "start", "server\/server.js" ]`
3. `CMD forever start server/server.js`

But each of them has failed.

The first two ran as `"forever start server"` ... notice the missing `/server.js` piece.

The last one ran as `"/bin/sh -c 'forever "`

So what is the correct syntax to place `forever start server/server.js` inside a `Dockerfile` to run it as a detached container?

Comment: Create a script, copy that into your container, set that as your `CMD`?

Comment: fair enough, upvoted as workaround, still looking to hear back on a syntax solution though :)

Comment: `sh -c` of your command?

Comment: @user2915097 - not sure what you are asking me

Comment: I was asking you what Armin Braun wrote

Answer (score 1):

I've just run into the same issue with starting a Java application inside the docker container when running it.

From the docker reference you have three opportunities:

```
CMD ["executable","param1","param2"]
CMD ["param1","param2"]
CMD command param1 param2
```

Have a look here: [Docker CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

I'm not familiar with JavaScript, but assuming that the application you want to start is a Java application:

```
CMD ["/some path/jre64/bin/java", "server.jar", "start", "forever", ...]
```

And as the others in your comments say, you could also add the script via docker `ADD` or `COPY` in your `Dockerfile` and start it with docker `RUN`.

Yet another solution would be to run the docker container and mount a directory with the desired script via docker `run .. -v HOSTDIR:CONTAINERDIR` inside the container and trigger that script with `docker exec`.

Have a read here: [Docker Filemounting](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/) + [Docker Exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/)

Comment: Thanks! The non-functional permutations that I listed in my original Q were based off the docs for Docker CMD. I will start evaluating workarounds once I'm sure there isn't anyone who knows of the appropriate syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Just run it via `sh -c` as suggested in the comments,
The syntax is:

```
CMD["/bin/sh", "-c", "'forever start server/server.js'"]
```

In case your tool requires a login shell to run, maybe try this one too:

```
CMD["/bin/bash", "-lc", "'forever start server/server.js'"]
```

This should work fine, having the same effect as putting the command into a standard sh shell in a single line.

Comment: Didn't work but I'm going to dig further as to why and post back.

Comment: update with a second alternative, maybe it's just a login shell thing ?

Comment: So a helpful mentor revealed that a container immediately stops unless the commands are running in foreground. So I added a foreground `tail` command: `forever start server/server.js && tail -f $(forever list | grep 'server/server.js' | awk '{print $8}');`